# Apache Rewrite RULE

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

People I have been working for days in this and I,m no able to make it work.

I,m trying to do a RewriteRule in my apache server but is not working.

if i use a simple url like this it works perfect.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(/.php/m/) htp://www.index.php
```

but if i use a complex url dont work , something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(/index.php?option=com_rsform&Itemid=8&lang=en) htp://www.index.php
```

does some body know why apache is not understanding this url what i,m missing

**index.php?option=com_rsform&Itemid=8&lang=en**

Comment: What do you mean by www.index.php? that sounds weird

Comment: sorry htp://www.index.php is only for the example, the real url will be something like htp://www.mydomain.com/index.php,

but my real problem is the first url 

index.php?option=com_rsform&Itemid=8&lang=en

Apache won,t rewrite when i hit that url it seems that it don,t recognize the url or don,t understand it "

Comment: Have you tried escaping the `?` (replace it with `\?`). It has a special meaning when used in a regular expression, as you're doing.

Comment: yes i try it like this: index.php\?option=com_rsform&ItemId=8&lang=en 
but din,t work

Comment: Actually I don't think the query part is included in the match with a RewriteRule. You can use a `RewriteCond` expression using %{QUERY_STRING} though.

Answer (score 4):

The query part is not included when you match an URL with a RewriteRule, see this part of [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> What is matched?
>
> The Pattern will initially be matched
>   against the part of the URL after the
>   hostname and port, and before the
>   query string. If you wish to match
>   against the hostname, port, or query
>   string, use a RewriteCond with the
>   %{HTTP_HOST}, %{SERVER_PORT}, or
>   %{QUERY_STRING} variables
>   respectively.

As suggested by the docs, you can use a RewriteCond expression to match on `%{QUERY_STRING}`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_rsform&Itemid=8&lang=en$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.index.php
```

Note that this only works when the query string is exactly the one you're matching. An equivalent query string in which the order of the arguments is changed, f.i. `option=com_rsform&lang=en&Itemid=8`, will not be matched. So in this case, I think you'd be better to send *all* requests to your PHP script, and have that look at `$_GET` and decide whether to forward or not.